# Django ORM group by

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have the following model.

```
Class A(models.Model):
    tmp_field = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    ...
```

Now I want to fetch only `id`s and group them together based on the `tmp` field.

My query looks like

```
A.objects.all().values('id')
```

So I want something like this.

```
[
    {tmp1: [id1, id2, id3]},
    {tmp2: [id5, id6, id7]},
    {tmp3: [id12, id213, id1299]}
    ...
]
```

How do I group them by `tmp_field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your values queryset to fetch the `tmp` field as well

```
queryset = A.objects.all().values('id', 'tmp')
```

then construct the dictionary you need using a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for q in queryset:
    d[q['tmp']].append(q['id'])
```

The result `d` will be a dictionary with `tmp` as the keys. This is slightly different than in your question (you have a list of dictionaries, each with one key). You can adjust the code if you need a different data structure.

Comment: That's one way. But I was thinking of avoiding the python processing. Is there no way to do it via a Django query.

Comment: No, there isn't an easy way to get the grouping you want using the Django ORM.